# Java BMI with Kilograms and inches

Tags: java

Hi im trying to calculate the bmi for kilograms and for inches. for 5 ft 8 inches the variable for hgt would be 5.8
What is the formula for this? thanks

```
 public static String GetMSG(double Kilo, double hgt)
      {
          double BMI = 00.00;
          String MSG = "";


//calculate bmi?    

          if(BMI < 18.50)
          {
              MSG = "Under";
          }
          else if(BMI >= 18.50 && BMI <= 24.99)
          {
              MSG = "Normal";
          }
          else if(BMI >= 25.00 && BMI <= 29.99)
          {
              MSG = "Over";
          }
          else if(BMI > 29.99)
          {
              MSG = "HUGE";
          }



          return MSG;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't 5 ft 8 inches be `5.6666..` feet?

Comment: Kilograms and *inches*? ewwww.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BMI in inches according Wikipedia is calculated as

```
= ( weight in pounds / (height in in)^2 )* 703
```

Since your weight is in kilograms you need to mulitply it by ~2.2 to get the weight in pounds. 
Then use the above formula to calculate your BMI

Comment: or more simply, it's kg / m^2. probably saner to convert to metric.